# How to lowercase a nested key in I18Next

Tags: javascript, i18next

Say I have a translation (in a JSON file) like:

```
{
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Doe",
    "welcome": "Welcome $t(first) $t(last)",
}
```

Is there an option to lowecase the referenced keys?
So instead of "Welcome John Doe" it would output "Welcome john doe".

Comment: Maybe his can help you: https://github.com/i18next/i18next/issues/765

Comment: Yes, I found that solution but that is working with an extra variable I need to specify from the outside. And I liked the clean approach with nesting so much.

Comment: I did not found that thread though. It is from 2016 so maybe it is supported now. Can not seem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) syntax.

> The get syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.

```js
var obj = {
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Doe",
    get welcome() {
      return `Welcome ${this.first.toLowerCase()} ${this.last.toLowerCase()}`;
    }
};
console.log(obj.welcome);
```

Comment: Okay, that looks nice. But...my translations are in a json file

Comment: If you can update the translations with get syntax then simply JSON parse will fulfill your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a formatter and then apply it in the translation file:

In your config:

```
i18n
  .init({
    interpolation: {
      format: function format(value, format, lng) {
        switch (format) {
          case "lowercase":
            return value.toUpperCase();
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

And then in your language file:

```
"first": "John",
"last": "Doe",
"welcome": "Welcome $t(first, lowercase) $t(last, lowercase)",
```